# How to display codes on a web page that are stored in a table?

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting

I am doing a little academic project based on online examination with asp.net c#, So there have to display number of question and answer as multiple choice, and I has used a data list view to display questions and answers on page. But the problem is programming codes are displaying like normal text.

My requirement is to display the programs codes by **line wise** and with **coloured keywords & data types etc**..

I am using a label tool to display the question and programs that are stored in SQL table with VARCHAR(MAX) data type. If the programs need to be stored in a separate file like XML or any other please give me some idea how to do this?

My page looks likes:
[image: In question label I want to display the code statements line wise. How do I do this?]

I need to display the question label as:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: This has nothing to do with .net - that's Java (re-tagged)

Answer (score 0):

Use [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/), simple to use also.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're asking how to display some lines of Java code on a web page so that

- it looks like properly indented Java code, and doesn't end up in one single long line
- it has syntax coloring.

The first part is easily done using a `<pre>` HTML tag:

```
<pre>
some lines of Java code
</pre>
```

The `pre` HTML tag is used to preserve line breaks and spaces.

For syntax coloring, consider using some JavaScript library like [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

Comment: yeah your correctly understood what my need is.. what works this <c:out /> tag?

Comment: Forget it. I thought you wanted to do this with a JSP. Use whatever asp.net provides to display a string and escape its HTML special characters (<, >, &)